# Sequelize Update/save has no effect on Table row

Tags: mysql, typescript, sequelize.js

We have a MySql DB on AWS, and we are using Lambdas with CDK, built on Typescript.
We have many CRUD operations across various lambdas.
However, on one lambda, the update of a row on a Table is not working.
An integration test run on a local DB works fine, and the affected rows give expected results. But running on AWS for this use case, calling the exact method that was integration tested, simply has no effect. The operation returns 0 affected rows, and no ValidationError is thrown, despite the transaction having changed data fields. We have tried using both the sequelize update method, and the save method. One interesting aspect is that the update query works fine if we update an old field. For the brand new fields, the update does not work. The DB migrations for new fields were run identically for the local integration test DB and the AWS DB.
The team cannot work out the issue.
Any ideas?

Code example:

```
async function updateMyValuesInUserDb(myParam: string, user: UserDbModel): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const value1 = getValue1(myParam)
        const value2 = getValue2(myParam)
      
        user.myNewField1 = value1
        user.myNewField2 = value2
        await user.save()
}
```

Model:

```
@Table({
    tableName: 'User',
    freezeTableName: true
})
export class UserDbModel extends Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    @AutoIncrement
    @Unique
    @Column
    id!: number

    @Column
    username: string

    @Column
    firstName: string

    @Column
    lastName: string

    @IsEmail
    @Unique
    @Column
    email: string

    @Default(false)
    @Column
    myNewField1: boolean

    @AllowNull(true)
    @Default(null)
    @Column
    myNewField2: number

    @UpdatedAt
    @Column
    updatedAt: Date

}
```

Comment: Please show the model defintion

Comment: I have added the model.

Comment: have you tried `printf` debugging? i found a bunch of sequelize on aws problem that seems to be very random, lambda skipping code is one of them. also, raising the issue to aws would be nice.

Comment: We added sequelize logging, and the update query does not execute at all. Only the select query that we do beforehand, on the same table.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the function?

Comment: @Anatoly Please see the update in the description about only certain fields being updated. The new fields won't update, only the old. I have also tried manually setting the values, to ensure the types are what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that although the integration tests were using the latest User model, the deployed code onto AWS was using an outdated User model, due to a package being out of date in package.json. We use symlinks to connect packages, and the deploy from local should factor in the symlink.  Unfortunately, the symlink only worked for the integration test. We could have discovered this earlier if we had opened up the deployed/built code, and searched for the new fields.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this answer. I ran into the exact same issue; my model definition was out of date. Frustrating that Sequelize does not give any error messaging, just silently fails to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `getValue1()` and the `getValue2()` functions are asynchronous calls and need to have the `await` keyword applied so that the runtime will wait for the `Promises` to `resolve`.

Comment: These functions are synchronous, and when logging, we can verify that the values are correct.